# implement tree structure as list in R

Tags: r, tree, binary-tree

I'm trying to implement this simple tree structure as a list in R:

```
  1
 / \
2  3
  / \
 4  5
```

What I tried is this:

```
tree <- list(1, list(2, 3, list(4, 5)))

> tree
[[1]]
[1] 1

[[2]]
[[2]][[1]]
[1] 2

[[2]][[2]]
[1] 3

[[2]][[3]]
[[2]][[3]][[1]]
[1] 4

[[2]][[3]][[2]]
[1] 5
```

Is this correct? From my understanding this tree looks like this:

```
   1
 / \ \
2  3  .
     / \
     4  5
```

**update** :

I also tried this:

```
tree <- list(1, list(2, c(3, list(4, 5))))
```

but it looks wrong, too

Comment: Have you looked at **[`data.tree`](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/data.tree/vignettes/data.tree.html#trees)**? Pretty cool package.

Comment: Also have a look a the [ape](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/ape/index.html) package that uses tree structures fairly robustly and efficiently (using edge tables rather than nested lists).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider the `data.tree` package. It prints the structure of nested lists nicely:

```
tree <- list("1" = 1, 
             "2" = list(2), 
             "3" = list(3, "4" = list(4), "5" = list(5)))

data.tree::FromListSimple(tree, nodeName = "1")
```

Returns:

```
  levelName
1 1        
2  ¦--2    
3  °--3    
4      ¦--4
5      °--5
```

Comment: so the solution in my case is `tree <- list(1, list(2), list(3, list(4), list(5)))`, correct?

Answer (score 1):

The Tree just needs the node name.

```
tree <- list(data=1, 
             lchild=list(data=2), 
             rchild=list(data=3, 
                         lchild=list(data=4), 
                         rchild=list(data=5)))
```